# SerializationException in LoadFrom'ed .NET Class Library

Tags: c#, deserialization, dynamic-loading

I'm getting a SerializationException with a message that it can't find the assembly, when I deserialize in a class that's been called through reflection.  The test solution has a console app and a class library.

Here's the whole app:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            //  Dynamically link ClassLibrary.dll, construct a Class1, and call it's Test().
            Assembly classLibraryAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(
                "..\\..\\..\\ClassLibrary\\bin\\Debug\\ClassLibrary.dll" );
            Type classLibraryClassType = classLibraryAssembly.GetType(
                "ClassLibrary.Class1" );
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = classLibraryClassType.GetConstructor(
                Type.EmptyTypes );
            object classLibrary = constructorInfo.Invoke( null );
            object[] parameters = new object[ 0 ];
            MethodInfo methodInfo = classLibraryClassType.GetMethod(
                "Test", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
            methodInfo.Invoke( classLibrary, parameters );
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the whole class library:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            //  Serialize an object, then deserialize it.
            byte[] serializedObject;
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();
            class2.SomeString = "Hello";
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using ( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize( memoryStream, class2 );
                serializedObject = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            using ( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
            {
                memoryStream.Write( serializedObject, 0, serializedObject.Length );
                memoryStream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
                class2 = (Class2) binaryFormatter.Deserialize( memoryStream );
            }
            string theString = class2.SomeString;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Class2
    {
        public string SomeString;
    }
}
```

The line:

```
class2 = (Class2) binaryFormatter.Deserialize( memoryStream );
```

is causing a SerializationException, with the message:

```
Unable to find assembly 'ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I find this odd, especially since it's running in that assembly.  I suspect that this is an issue of the Load versus the LoadFrom context, but I don't really understand those, or how to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems, show us the trace.

Comment: Copy that dll under your main EXE library.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Ofir for the suggestion to copy the DLL to the working directory.  The following change worked, allowing Load() to be used instead of LoadFrom():

```
File.Copy(
    "..\\..\\..\\ClassLibrary\\bin\\Debug\\ClassLibrary.dll",
    "ClassLibrary.dll",
    true );
Assembly classLibraryAssembly = Assembly.Load( "ClassLibrary" );
```

Thank you!